# Installing Packages to TeX Studio ( TikZ package)

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, installing

I am currently a new user of TeX studio, so i really don't know how to install packages ,particularly TikZ package, to TeX studio on my Computer. Also I am very open to suggestions about how can I start learning LaTex.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest that you have a look into [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, you can install MikTeX. In the Texworks interface, you can simply write your document with \usepackage{tikz}; MikTeX will ask whether to install the package for you, and you will only have to accept it. You might need to look into you settings to fix this; I am no longer on Windows and cannot check it for you.

If you are on Ubuntu (I don't know about other Linux systems), and you want to install a package (say, tikz), open your terminal and type

```
sudo apt search tikz
```

It will provide you with a list of relevant packages and their names. In this particular case, the result is quite the list. I don't know any other way of working through this than find the package that seems most relevant, and if in doubt, google it (packages.debian.org usually provides the required info, in my experience). In this case, tikz seems to be in texlive-pictures. I believe this specific package is automatically installed with texlive, but if it were not, you could use the command

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures
```

That'd do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you can download & install `LaTeX` packages using either [MikTeX](https://miktex.org/) or [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

If you are on Linux, you can download & install `LaTeX` packages using [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). Another way is open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run command `sudo apt install texlive`.

Installing `LaTeX` packages require good internet speed and disk space (more than 2 GB).

To learn `LaTeX`, I would suggest you to look into [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Main_Page).

Comment: Is TeX Maker suitable for installing these packages ? I installed TeX Maker shortly before ?

Comment: TeXMaker, like TeXStudio are LaTeX editors. You can compile documents using them, once the TeX packages are installed.

Comment: Tanvir, thank you so much !

Comment: Using texlive from the system is probably a bad idea because it installs fonts that end up exposed to the system. In the latest Ubuntu version, installing full TeXLive installs a version of the Roboto font htat messes with font rendering in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In TeXstudio on Windows with MikTeX installed, it is generally sufficient to write `\usepackage{<package_name>}` e.g. `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble (after `documentclass{article}` and before `begin{document}`). You do not need to directly interface with MikTeX.

For learning LaTeX, [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Creating_a_document_in_LaTeX) is excellent. Other useful resources include [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), the [TeXstudio user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html) and [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/) (for comprehensive package documentation, where Overleaf is insufficient). Seeing as you're using Tikz, you may also find [Tikzit](https://tikzit.github.io/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

In linux using apt or apt-get can use this command to install all depend to texlive:

```
apt install texlive*
```

or to search the correct package, can use :

```
apt search texlive
```

note, use this command as root user.